# Oracle Database: Combing columns in a pivot

Tags: oracle

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
  EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD, 
  EMPL_VAL_AMT, EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR, EMPL_FMONTH
  FROM EMPL_FCST
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(EMPL_VAL_AMT) 
  FOR (EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR)
  IN ((01,2018), (02,2018))
)
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
OTHER_SELECT_COLUMNS  |  EMPL_VAL_AMT  |  EMPL_FMONTH  |  EMPL_FYEAR
---------------------   --------------   -------------   ------------
          ABC                 1111             1             2018
          ABC                 1112             6             2019
```

NEEDED RESULT:

```
OTHER_SELECT_COLUMNS  |  1/2018  |  6/2019
---------------------   ---------  --------   
          ABC             1111       1112
```

ERROR:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
  EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD, 
  EMPL_VAL_AMT, EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR, EMPL_FMONTH
  FROM EMPL_FCST
)
PIVOT
(
 SUM(EMPL_VAL_AMT) 
 FOR (EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR)
 IN ((1,2018), (2,2018))
)
Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I am trying to combine `EMPL_FMONTH` and `EMPL_FYEAR` as the FOR in my pivot so the column heading looks like MM/YYYY across the top with the sum of `EMPL_VAL_AMT` under each column header. I feel like i need some kind of `EMPL_FMONTH||"/"||EMPL_FYEAR` statement in there in addition to getting the query to combine the fields into the FOR. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

column EMPL_FMONTH is repeated in the select statement.

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
  EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD, 
  EMPL_VAL_AMT, EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR
  FROM EMPL_FCST
)
PIVOT
(
 SUM(EMPL_VAL_AMT) 
 FOR (EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR)
 IN ((1,2018), (2,2018))
)
```

Comment: Omg I did EMPL_FMONTH twice. Thanks so much. I feel dumb.